# Extract English letters and numbers using regex

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have the following code that extracts the English letters from mixed English and Arabic letters

```
Sub Test()
Dim a           As Variant
Dim i           As Long

With Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Resize(, 3)
    a = .Value
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
            .Pattern = "[^\w_ ]+"
            a(i, 3) = Trim$(.Replace(a(i, 1), ""))
        Next i
    End With
    .Value = a
End With
End Sub
```

I need to change the pattern so as to be able to extract the numbers too .. so I need to extract the English letters and also the numbers.

Comment: Add `\d` after `\w`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked well

Comment: Why add `\d`?  [`[^\w_ ]`](https://regex101.com/r/tpkO1s/2)  matches a char other than ASCII letters, digits, `_`  and space. `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Your regex already does what you ask for.

Comment: It doesn't extract the numbers if the numbers are between the Arabic letters .. It just extracts the numbers between the English letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\d` after `\w` . This allows for extraction of numbers if the numbers are between the Arabic letters.

From comment by @Tiw / OP.